# How to select values from a column that have only specific values from another column and not other values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pgsql schema having a table that has two columns among others: id and status. status values are of varchar type ranging from '1' to '6'. I want to select values of id that have only specific status, precisely, one id having only one status ('1'), then another having two values ('1' ands '2'), then another having only three values ('1', '2' and '3') and so on.

This is for a pgsql database. I have tried using inner query joining with the same table.

```
select *
from srt s
join ( select id
       from srt
       group by id
       having count(distinct status) = 2
     ) t on t.id = s.id
where srt.status in ('1', '2')
limit 10
```

I used this to get the IDs having only status values 1 and 2 (and not having any rows with status values 3, 4, 5, 6) but didn't get the expected result

The expected result would be something like this

```
id  status
123 1
234 1
234 2
345 1
345 2
345 3
456 1
456 2
456 3
456 4
567 1
567 2
567 3
567 4
567 5
678 1
678 2
678 3
678 4
678 5
678 6
```

Comment: Do they have to be consecutive statuses?  For example when you specify "1,2,3" as target statuses, part of the result includes an id having exactly two statuses: does it have to be "1" and "2" or can it be "1" and "3", "2" and "3", etc.  Or would you want one id for each of those three cases?

Answer (score 0):

Move your where condition inside sub-query -

```
select *
from srt s
join ( select id
       from srt
       where status in ('1', '2')
       group by id
       having count(distinct status) = 2
     ) t on t.id = s.id
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the ids with consecutive statuses, you can do:

```
select id, max(status) as max_status
from srt s
group by id
having min(status) = 1 and
       max(status::int) = count(*);
```

Then, you can narrow this down to one example using `distinct on` and use `join` to bring in your results:

```
select s.*
from srt s join
     (select distinct on (max(status)) id, max(status) as max_status
      from srt s
      group by id
      having min(status) = 1 and
             max(status::int) = count(*)
      order by max_status asc
     ) ss
     on ss.id = s.id
order by ss.max_status, s.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one.  My solution is to first specify a list of the "target statuses" you want to match:

```
with target_statuses(s) as ( values (1),(2),(3) )
```

Then JOIN your `srt` table to it and count the occurrences grouped by `id`.

```
with target_statuses(s) as ( values (1),(2),(3) )
select id, count(*), row_number() OVER (partition by count(*) order by id) rownum
    from srt
    join target_statuses on status=s
    group by id
)
```

This query also captures a row number, which we'll later use to limit it to the first id that has one match, the first id that has two matches, etc.  Note the `order by` clause... I assume you want the alphabetically lowest id first in each case, but you may change that.

Since you can't put a window function in a `HAVING` clause, I wrap up the whole result at `ids_and_counts_of_statuses` and perform a follow-up query that rejoins it with the `srt` table to output it:

```
with ids_and_counts_of_statuses as(

with target_statuses(s) as ( values (1),(2),(3) )
select id, count(*), row_number() OVER (partition by count(*) order by id) rownum
    from srt
    join target_statuses on status=s
    group by id
)
select srt.id, srt.status
from ids_and_counts_of_statuses
join srt on ids_and_counts_of_statuses.id=srt.id
where rownum=1;
```

Note that I have changed your varchar values to integers just so I didn't have to type quite so much punctuation.  It works, here's an example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wwob31uiNgr9aAkZoe1Jgs/0